# Why would a cloud page not show in Journey Builder if the form has a name and id

Tags: journeybuilder, smart-capture

Does anyone know what I need to change to the below HTML to get the form to show up in Journey Builder or is something else needed?

The ID and name are unique.

```
      <script id="smartcapture-script-L4Y673bnba">
         var scFormLoaded = function () {
          window.ScForm.init({"gearID":"L4Y673bnba","smartCaptureFormID":101,"sourceKey":"27AF5EF9-1F5B-4116-A91C-FFF93FCB930B","source":"dataExtension","triggeredSend":"","confirmationMessage":"Thank you for your submission.","buttonText":"Submit","formStyling":{"background-color":"transparent","margin-top":"0px","margin-right":"0px","margin-bottom":"0px","margin-left":"0px","padding-top":"0px","padding-right":"0px","padding-bottom":"0px","padding-left":"0px","text-align":"left","margin":"0px","padding":"35px"},"fieldStyling":{"width":"200px"},"buttonStyling":{"background-color":"#FF0000","border-color":"#FF0000","border-radius":"3px","border-style":"solid","-webkit-border-radius":"3px","-moz-border-radius":"3px","color":"#FFFFFF","font-family":"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","font-size":"16px","line-height":"normal","padding":"10px"},"onSubmitShouldGotoUrl":true,"onSubmitGotoUrlType":2,"onSubmitGotoUrl":"http://www.timeout.com"});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "Use in Journey Builder" flag checked? I know I have had problems in the past with not being able to see the form in the drop drown list because of that.

[image]